# Seifert-van Kampen theorem, classical version

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, group-homomorphism, fundamental-groups

This is from Munkres' Topology page 431:

> **Theorem 70.2** (Seifert-van Kampen theorem, classical version). Assume the hypotheses of the preceding theorem. Let
>
> $$ j : \pi_1(U, x_0) * \pi_1(V, x_0) \longrightarrow \pi_1(X, x_0) $$
>
> be the homomorphism of the free product that extends the homomorphisms
> $j_1$ and $j_2$ induced by inclusion. Then $j$ is surjective, and its
> kernel is the least normal subgroup $N$ of the free product that
> contains all elements represented by words of the form
>
> $$ (i_{1}(g))^{-1} i_{2}(g)), $$
>
> for $g \in \pi_{1}(U \cap V, x_{0}).$

and by hypotheses of the preceding theorem it means that $X$ is a topological space and $U$, $V$ open subsets of $X$ such that $X = U \cup V$ and $x_0 \in U \cap V$

$j_1:\pi_1(U,x_0)\to\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and $ j_2:\pi_1(V,x_0)\to\pi_1(X,x_0)$ are inclusion induced homomorphisms.

I read the proof and understood it but something is really bothering me and that is how do we know that the homomorphism $j$ mentioned in the theorem even exists?

Comment: This comes down to understanding the definition of the free product.

Comment: can you elaborate on it a bit?

Comment: I'd start here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product

Comment: I've read the definition before so if you could explain how this comes down to understanding the definition it would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

It tells you: $j_1:U\subset X$ and $j_2:V\subset X$ induce maps on $\pi_1$, $\pi_1(U)\to\pi_1(X)$ and $\pi_1(V)\to\pi_1(X)$, and these are genuine homomorphisms, and if you have two groups $A,B$ and a third group $C$ and homomorphisms $A\to C,B\to C$ then there is a unique associated homomorphism $A\ast B\to C$. In this case with $A=\pi_1(U),B=\pi_1(V),C=\pi_1(X)$, there is a unique homomorphism $j:\pi_1(U)\ast\pi_1(V)\to\pi_1(X)$ associated to $j_1,j_2$.

Comment: is this a trivial theorem or has a name because it hasn't been mentioned in the book

Comment: This is the *defining property of the free product* or sometimes also called the *universal property of the free product*, that any pair of morphisms into the same group extends uniquely to a morphism from the free product into the target group

Comment: @Sven-Ole Behrend thank you, I got it.

Comment: @DavoodKarimi check out tom leinster's [basic category theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) for funsies. the free product is the coproduct in groups.